# Return info of object using unique ID code

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I want to make a system where you can input some information about an animal, I currently have a cat and a dog implemented. However I also want the user to be able to search for a specific animal using their unique chipID's. The animals have three variables assigned to them: name, age and chipid. Name is a string, but age and chipid are ints.

Can someone show me how I would create a dog/cat object that uses these three variables and a system that can look them up. I currently input all of these variables using a textbox. It would also be nice to search using a button, so the user inputs the chipid in a textbox and when the user clicks on the button the rest of the information is shown in their textbox inputs.

Edit:

Hurray! I solved it myself, I had to create a little list to store my animals in and a function to look an individual animal using their unique ID but it worked out in the end. I really should've tried a little harder. Thank you guys for the advice on that! : )

Comment: Sounds like cat and dog should derive from ChippedAnimal that has these three common properties. I recommend not to store Age; store birthdate instead so you can calculate the age. Age is out of date as soon as it's stored

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: cat and dog both inherit from a class called Animal, and yes it's for school ;)

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)  [Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/13664939)

Comment: _"a system that can look them up"_ - If you have them in a datastructure, you already have such a system. Additionally / Alternatively to that you could keep them in a database, of course.

Comment: I'll have a final look myself, thanks for the guidelines btw!

Comment: As you have solved it, you can post and accept your own answer if you want. This achieves several things - it marks it as answered on the dashboard so other people know, it may over time lead to an increase in your own reputation/badges and (perhaps cynically) it also tells your classmates the answer (so maybe post it *after* the homework is due in) :D

Answer (score 1):

In modern programming, there is a tendency to separate your data (= the model) from how you display the data (= the view). This will make it easier to reuse the data if you want to change the way your view it, or the way you input the data. Apart from better changeability and reusability, the procedures will be smaller, therefore they will be easier to understand, and to unit test.

To connect the model to the view, an adapter is needed, quite often called the viewmodel. The abbreviation of model / view / viewmodel is MVVM. Read some theories about this.

So you  have some animals, among which Cats and Dogs. Every Animal has a Name, an Age and a ChipId. Probably Cats and Dogs have more functionality, they differ from each other.

Are you sure that you want to save the `Age` of an Animal? This would mean that you would have to regularly update this value. Wouldn't it be better to remember something like `BirthDate`?

```
class Animal
{
    public int ChipId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDate {get; set;}

    public int Age => (DateTime.Today - this.BirthDay.Date).TotalDays / 365;
}
```

The formula for Age is not completely correct, you'll have to fiddle with leap years, and before and after BirthDate, but that is a bit out of scope of your question, you get the gist.

```
public class Cat : Animal
{
    ...
}
public class Dog : Animal
{
    ...
}
```

> Can someone show me how I would create a dog/cat object that uses these three variables and a system that can look them up.

I think you do know how to Create a Dog or a Cat. Let's assume you want to make several of them, and you want to be able to search for them.

You didn't tell: are the ChipIds unique for all Animals, or can a Cat have the same ChipId as a Dog? Let's assume they all use the same kind of chips, so the ChipIds are unique.

```
class AnimalCollection
{
    public void Add(Animal animal) {...}
    public Animal Find(int chipId) {...}
}
```

There are several .NET classes that represent sequences of similar items. Which method you use depends on what you want to do with the collection: how often do you add / remove / items, and how often do you fetch one specific item.

You seem to want to fetch an Animal by ChipId. If you need to do this often, the most efficient method would be to create a Dictionary of Animals. If you will be Adding / Removing Animals far more often than fetching them (which I doubt), then consider to use a different kind of collection.

The nice thing is, that because I created an `AnimalCollection` class, users of my class (= code, not operators), won't know which method I use internally to store the animals, so you are free to change it, if later you find out that you didn't make the right decision.

```
class AnimalCollection
{
    private IDictionary<int, Animal> animals = new Dictionary<int, Animal>();

    public void Add(Animal animal)
    {
        this.animals.Add(animal.ChipId, animal);
    }

    public Animal Find(int chipId)
    {
        if (this.Animals.TryGetValue(chipId, out Animal fetchedAnimal)
        {
            return fetchedAnimal;
        }
        else
        {
            // There is no Animal with this ChipId
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Consider to Add checks that the ChipId is unique before Adding the new Animal. If you don't you will get an exception. Which method you use depends on how big the chance is that you try to add a new Animal with an existing ChipId.

I think you want to be able to save the Animals in the collection, so you can get them the next time you start your program. Of course you want to hide how the data is stored. It can be a simple CSV file, or XML, JSON, or maybe even a database. All we know is that you can put Animals in a Repository, and later, after a restart of your program fetch them again.

Which method you actually use to Load / Save Animals depends on the amount of Animals, and whether they relate to other collections, like Owners, Locations, Food, etc.

If there are not a lot of them, you can save the items in a file. If you will have thousands of Animals with several relations, consider to save them in a database.

Because database is a bit out of scope of this question, I'll store the animals in an XML file. To make future changes possible, I'll hide that it is XML.

```
public class AnimalRepository
{
    private XmlSerializer animalSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Animal[]));

    public IEnumerable<Animal> Load(string fileName)
    {
        using (var textReader = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            return this.Load(textReader);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Animal> Load(TextReader textReader)
    {
        return (Animal[])this.animalSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    }

    public void Save(string fileName, IEnumerable<Animal> animals
    {
        using (var textWriter = File.CreateText(fileName))
        {
            return this.Save(textWriter);
        }
    }

    public void Save(TextWriter textWriter, IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
    {
        this.animalSerializer.Serialize(textWriter);
    }
}
```

Users of this class won't have to know the format in which the Animals are stored. All they know is that it is stored in a file. If later you decide to change the format to CSV or XML, you are free to do so. After this change you can even support legacy files that were saved in XML before the change.

### The View

Apparently you want to make a form where an operator can create a new Cat or Dog, and give it a Name and BirthDate (or Age if you want, I won't mention this again).

The question is: how do you get the ChipId? Do you have a ChipId reader? Or maybe the operator types the Id?

Of course you want your code to be maintainable, so if in the first version the operator types the ChipId, and later you read it from a Chip reader, you don't want to make a lot of changes to your code.

```
public int ReadChipId {...}
public DateTime ReadBirthDate {...}
public string ReadName {...}
```

The implementation depends on what kind of controls you gave the operator. Make sure, that if the operator makes a mistake in input format, it is checked here. So if the data is invalid, the operator is warned, **thou shallst never return invalid dates!**

```
public string ReadName()
{
    return this.textBoxName.Text;
}
```

If you also want to write name, consider:

```
public string DisplayedName
{
    get => this.textBoxName.Text;
    set => this.textBoxName.Text = value;
}
```

You could do the same with the BirthDate. Another method would be to use visual studio designer to add DateTimePicker control. Use visual studio properties to set the display format

```
public DateTime DisplayedBirthDate
{
    get => this.dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value;
    set => this.dateTimePicker.BirthDate.Value = value;
}
```

Of course you can use a TextBox for this, but in that case you'll have to check whether the input is correct:

```
public DateTime GetBirthDate()
{
    string birthDateText = this.textBoxBirthDate.Text;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(birthDateText, out DateTime birthDate)
    {
        // input correct:
        return birthDate;
    }
    else
    {
        // incorrect input
        // TODO: decide how to warn the operator: MessageBox?
        return DateTime.MaxValue; // so the caller knows that this is an incorrect Date
    }
}
```

For the ChipId consider to use a NumericUpDown control, so you know that the input is always an int. Of course you hide this in a property:

```
int DisplayedChipId
{
    get => ...
    set => ...
}
```

If you know about invalid ChipIds, like negative numbers, or zero, handle it here.

I almost forgot: use a ComboBox to tell which type of Animal must be added. Use the visual designer to give it a value: "Cat", "Dog", ...

The operator fills in the fields and presses `Add` button. Use visual studio designer to add the event handler:

```
void OnButtonAdd_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.AddAnimal();
}
```

You also want to find an animal by Id, so you need an input item to type the requested animal Id:

```
int RequestedAnimalId => this.numericUpdownRequestedAnimalId.Value;
```

### The ViewModel

This is the glue between the displayed items and your model.

```
Animal CreateAnimalFromDisplay()
{
    switch (this.SelectedAnimalType)        // Read the combo box with the animal type
    {
        case Cat:
           return new Cat
           {
               ChipId = this.DisplayedChipId,
               Name = this.DisplayedName,
               ...
           };
        case Dog:
           return new Dog
           {
               ChipId = this.DisplayedChipId,
               Name = this.DisplayedName,
               ...
           };
       ...
    }
}

private void AddAnimal()
{
    Animal createdAnimal = this.CreatAnimal();
    this.AnimalCollection.Add(Animal);
}
```

To find an Animal:

```
private Animal GetRequestedAnimal()
{
    return this.AnimalCollection(this.RequestedAnimalId);
}

private void DisplayFoundAnimal(Animal foundAnimal)
{
     ... // fill textBoxes, etc
}

private void DisplayRequestedAnimal()
{
    Animal foundAnimal = this.GetRequestedAnimal();
    if (foundAnimal != null)
    {
        this.DisplayFoundAnimal(foundAnimal);
    }
    else
    {
         // Animal not found. TODO: decide how to react
    }
}

private void OnButtonFind_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.DisplayRequestedAnimal();
}
```

Do you see, that because I separated the model from the view, most methods are only a few lines. It is easy to see for each method what it does, it will be easy to unit test the model methods. If you want to change something in the view, changes are minimal, similarly if you want to change the model, most view elements won't have to change.